# Block status bar in all applications

Tags: android, notifications, block, statusbar, status

I need to block status bar in all applications. I know it is possible becouse it was done in SureLock. I can do that in my activity with this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    try
    {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
            Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
            Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
            Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
            collapse .setAccessible(true);
            collapse .invoke(service);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
            try {
                Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                collapse .setAccessible(true);
                collapse .invoke(service);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But how do that in all apps like in [SureLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock)?

Comment: What exactly you mean by block status bar? You want to hide it?

Comment: Yes. If someone tries to show notification bar is automatically hidden. Just like in SureLock. I'm not intersted in full screnn because I can't open others apps in full screen without notification bar.

Comment: Did you ever find solution to this? I know exactly what you mean and am having trouble with this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna hide the status bar throughout the application then you can do that through the manifest file.

See the implementation here
http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#40

Comment: I'm not intersted in full screnn because I can't open others apps in full screen without notification bar.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. Its works for me

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    try
    {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
            Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
            Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
            Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
            collapse.setAccessible(true);
            collapse.invoke(service);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
            try {
                Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                collapse.setAccessible(true);
                collapse.invoke(service);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```